# A question about second moment of gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ be a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I am trying to evaluate 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^2 I(X \geq b)),
$$
where $I(X \geq b)$ is the indicator random variable which equals $1$ whenever the event $\{X \geq b\}$ happens. Is there any closed form expression for the above quantity in terms of some known functions?

My attempt: For simplicity I took $\mu=0,\sigma^2=1$ and thus 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^2 I(X \geq b)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{b}^\infty x^2e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx.
$$
Since we don't have any closed form expressions for the integral I took the expansion of $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and integrated term by term but this is not yielding any useful information.

Comment: You can't really do any better than that unfortunately. People might say that you can use the error function, but at best, you're only rewriting the problem in different language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By parts,

$$\int_{b}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2/2} dx=-\left.xe^{-x^2/2}\right|_b^\infty+\int_{b}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx,$$ so that

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2 I(X \geq b))=\frac{be^{-b^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\mathbb{E}(I(X \geq b)).$$

The term on the right is the complimentary of the Gaussian cdf, i.e. the error function.